# Weave + Ansible Docker Module

Tags: docker, ansible, weave

I'm using weave to launch some containers which form a database cluster. I have gotten this working manually on two hosts in EC2 by doing the following:

```
$HOST1> weave launch
$HOST2> weave launch $HOST1
$HOST1> eval $(weave env)
$HOST2> eval $(weave env)
$HOST1> docker run --name neo-1 -d -P ... my/neo4j-cluster
$HOST2> docker run --name neo-2 -d -P ... my/neo4j-cluster
$HOST3> docker run --name neo-1 -d -P -e ARBITER=true ... my/neo4j-cluster
```

I can check the logs and everthing starts up ok.

When using ansible I can get the above to work using the `command: ...` module and an environment variable:

```
- name: Start Neo Arbiter
command: 'docker run --name neo-2 -d -P ... my/neo4j-cluster'
environment:
  DOCKER_HOST: 'unix:///var/run/weave/weave.sock'
```

As that's basically all `eval $(weave env)` does.

**But** when I use the `docker` module for ansible, even with the `docker_url` parameter set to the same thing you see above with `DOCKER_HOST`, DNS does not resolve between hosts. Here's what that looks like:

```
  - name: Start Neo Arbiter
    docker:
      image: "my/neo4j-cluster:{{neo4j_version}}"
      docker_url: unix:///var/run/weave/weave.sock
      name: neo-3
      pull: missing
      state: reloaded
      detach: True
      publish_all_ports: True
```

OR

```
  - name: Start Neo Arbiter
    docker:
      image: "my/neo4j-cluster:{{neo4j_version}}"
      docker_url: unix:///var/run/weave/weave.sock
      name: neo-3
      pull: missing
      state: reloaded
      detach: True
      publish_all_ports: True
    environment:
        DOCKER_HOST: 'unix:///var/run/weave/weave.sock'
```

Neither of those work. The DNS does not resolve so the servers never start. I do have other server options (like SERVER_ID for neo4j, etc set just not shown here for simplicity).

Anyone run into this? I know the docker module for ansible uses `docker-py` and stuff. I wonder if there's some type of incompatibility with weave?

**EDIT**

I should mention that when the containers launch they actually show up in WeaveDNS and *appear* to have been added to the system. I can ping the local hostname of each container as long as its on the host. When I go to the other host though, it cannot ping the ones on the other host. This despite them registering in WeaveDNS (`weave status dns`) and `weave status` showing correct # of peers and established connections.

Comment: In the meantime my workaround I've taken is to use the `command` module. I'm going to leave this open as its still an issue AFAICT.

Comment: Firstly, I wonder if the Ansible Docker module uses Python client or calls `docker`? Secondly, please confirm that requests go through to the proxy by checking `docker logs weaveproxy`?

Comment: @errordeveloper yes it uses docker-py and I cannot recall the logs. I'll be reverting changes to test this weekend to try things suggested and will post back.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue above?

Comment: @MateVarga No, I used the `command` module. I suspect it has something to do with the way the python lib was implemented, when compared with the CLI, but can't be sure.

Comment: @alph486 in my case, the problem turned out to be the missing host -- I now use docker_container module and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the client sending a `HostConfig` struct in the Docker `start` request, which is not really how you're supposed to do it but is supported by Docker "[for backwards compatibility](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.19/#start-a-container)".

Weave has been [fixed to cope](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/pull/1449), but the fix is not in a released version yet. You could try the [latest snapshot version](http://docs.weave.works/weave/latest_release/troubleshooting.html#snapshots) if you're brave.

You can probably kludge it by explicitly setting the DNS resolver to the docker bridge IP in your containers' config - weave has an undocumented helper `weave docker-bridge-ip` to find this address, and it generally won't change.